# WCF returning wrong view output

Tags: wcf

Here I struck in some strange situation.

I created a view in SQL Server

```
Create View [Adm].[VwSurveyReport]
as 
SELECT q.QuestionID,q.Question,p.dtStart,p.dtEnd,u.OrgCode,u.UserID,u.RoleID,
(case tc.blanswer 
when 1 then 1 
when 0 then 0
end) as AnsYes,
(case tc.blanswer 
when 1 then 0 
when 0 then 1
end) as AnsNo
from dbo.SurveyQuestions as q
left outer join dbo.surveyTransChild as tc on tc.questionID=q.questionID
left outer join dbo.surveyTransParent as tp on tp.SurveyTransID=tc.SurveyTransID
left outer join dbo.SurveyParent as p on p.surveyID=tp.surveyID
left outer join adm.masFEUser as u on tp.Userid=u.Userid
where p.dtStart IS Not NULL
GO
```

and my code behind is

```
List<ThePayWcfRef.VwSurveyReport> data = new List<ThePayWcfRef.VwSurveyReport>();
data =  (from v in entities.VwSurveyReports
     where 1 == 1 
     select v).ToList();
```

When I run select query in SQL Server it is showing exact output which I want

```
UserID  RoleID  AnsYes  AnsNo
m6018upl    2   1   0
m6018upl    2   1   0
m6018app1   4   1   0
m6018app1   4   0   1
```

but in my code behind I am getting wrong data into "data" list

```
UserID  RoleID  AnsYes  AnsNo
m6018app1   4   1   0
m6018app1   4   0   1
m6018app1   4   1   0
m6018app1   4   0   1
```

**AnsYes, AnsNo and UserID are wrong**

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK - in your Entity Framework model, can you please check **which columns** of your view are part of the `EntityKey` property of that entity?

Comment: Where does WCF come into play in this question? Are you building a service?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your EF model looks like - but the issue with views in Entity Framework often boils down to this:

- since a view by default doesn't have a primary key, EF will "infer" an "entity key" based on all the columns in the view that are guaranteed to be `NOT NULL`
- those columns might (or might not) make a good *surrogate* primary key
- when EF loads the data, it will look at those columns in the primary key; if an entity with that same `EntityKey` has already been loaded from the database, EF will **not** load the data again, but reference that entity it already has in memory

All this together *can* lead to unexpected results on EF using views.

There are a number of solutions around this:

- make sure to include **all** primary keys from all included base tables in your view; that way, the table's primary keys **will** certainly be part of the view's *surrogate* primary key for EF and thus they will guarantee uniqueness
- create your own, individual *pseudo* primary key by having a e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()` column in your view, just to make sure each row has something that's unique for that row, in order to prevent EF from "short-circuiting" entities because it thinks it's already loaded that entity...